# where to put filter like logic in JSF2

Tags: jsf-2, java-ee-6, cdi

I am currently banging my head where to put a common logic for some authorization stuff in my Java EE 6/JSF 2 webapp:
I have the requirement, that all requests that come with a specific cookie should be redirected to another page.

I considered 3 solutions:

**1) use a servlet 3.0 filter (@WebFilter)**
this worked, i also could inject my managed beans there, but the managed beans require access to the faces externalContext, which at filter invocation time has not yet been set up, so i got NPE's calling the managed beans

**2) use a phase listener**
this feels awkward, because a phase listener cannot be a CDI component and so cannot inject other components (except via el-evaluation);  a phaseListener for me feels to technical to put navigation logic into it.

**3) in Seam 2.0 i could used "page actions"** for things like this, but it seems that this concept didn't make it into JSF 2.0

in seam this looked like:

```
<page view-id="/admin/*.jsf">
    <action execute="#{authenticator.checkAccess()}" />
</page>
```

Is it really, that JSF 2.0 does not have a concept to execute "controller logic" before rendering a page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JSF 2.x you can listen to page events like that:

```
<f:metadata>
   <f:event type="javax.faces.event.PreRenderViewEvent" listener="#authenticator.checkAccess()}" />
</f:metadata>
```

That is more or less equivalent to Seam 2 page action (you will have to filter out postbacks though). You can further enhance the default behavior with CDI-extensions like [Seam Faces](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/3/faces/latest/reference/en-US/html/). Probably it's a good idea if you have a look at the documentation and see what fits your needs...

Comment: hi jan, thank you for your quick answer, didn't know about that feature! So, if i want to be sure all my jsf pages are intercepted, the only way would be to assure that all jsf pages include that piece of code (e.g. via page composition)?

Comment: No no, that's certainly not the only way. If I were you I would investigate further in the filter-option - as this is a standard requirement for many JSF-applications there should certainly be a sophisticated solution for your question.