# JSF and j_security_check

Tags: jsf, j-security-check

I'm working on a webapp, using JSF; for the authenticaion I use a form, with its action set to *j_security_check?j_url=/faces/main.xhtml*; after successfull login the user is redirected to *main.xhtml*

My question is, is there a way, to call a ManagedBean method between

- j_security_check and
- main.xhtml rendering
- but without creating another view (say: loginRedirectView) or another servlet?

Thanks,
krisy

Comment: Sure. Just add a `preRenderView` event handler on *main.xhtml*, which will call a backing bean method

Comment: possible duplicate of [which phase should i use to intercept the login attempt in JSF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17019218/which-phase-should-i-use-to-intercept-the-login-attempt-in-jsf)